# How check member status on MSTEAMS

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

For a purpose of checking member status (online or offline) on MSTeams, I want to get member status by email.

I have approached [Bot Builder Microsoft Teams Extensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-teams) and write a sample code to get into my idea:

```
var teams = require("botbuilder-teams");

bot.dialog('FetchMemberInfo', function (session) {
    var memberEmail = 'billzeng@csc.com';

    var connector = new teams.TeamsChatConnector({
        appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
        appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
    });

    connector.fetchMemberInfo(session.message.address.serviceUrl, memberEmail, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            session.endDialog('There is some error');
        }
        else {
            var memberStatus = result.member.status;
            session.endDialog('%s', JSON.stringify(result));
        }
    });
});
```

I only have member's email and want to get member status. So, what place in my sample code need to be updated to get member information which include member status? I also welcome any other suggestion if there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we can get user status (online/offline) via Skype4Business API. Here is an example code:

```
var authContext = {
    id: botSetting.identifier,
    username: botSetting.username,
    password: botSetting.password,
    domain: botSetting.domain,
    _links: {},
    /*1 seconds*/
    messageInterval: 1000 * botSetting.messageInterval,
    /*30 seconds*/
    messageTimeout: 1000 * botSetting.messageTimeout,
    /*3 minutes, unit in second*/
    statusUpdateInterval: 1000 * botSetting.statusUpdateInterval,
    AppId: null,
    AppPath: null,
    EndPointId: botSetting.endpointId,
    Culture: botSetting.culture,
    UserAgent: botSetting.userAgent,
    /* default timeout to wait for user to accept message is 5 minutes */
    acceptMessageInvitationTimeout: botSetting.acceptMessageInvitationTimeout * 1000,
    logUnhandleEvent: botSetting.logUnhandleEvent,
    RootAppUrl: null,
    /*default is 30 seconds, unit in second*/
    statusAwarenessInterval: (CONFIG.PROACTIVE_MESSAGE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS || 30) * SECOND_TO_MILLISECONDS, //30 seconds
    remindProcessProactiveMsgInterval: 1000 * 60 * CONFIG.PROACTIVE_MESSAGE_REMIND_IN_MINUTES,
    proactive_interval: process.env.PROACTIVE_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES || 2
};
    
function getUserAvailibility(receiver){
    var url = authContext._embedded.people._links.self.href;
    var requestResourceUrl = stringFormat("{0}{1}/{2}/presence", authContext.BaseUri, 
                                           url, receiver);
    console.log("SkypeForBusinessBot getUserAvailibility " + receiver +
                " with url: " + requestResourceUrl);
    return $q.nfcall(request.get, requestResourceUrl, {
        headers: authContext.headers, json: true });
    }
```

Note: receiver is user's email

Comment: Sounds promising, thanks. Which module is required in the Node.js script for this functionality?

Comment: And what if you need to do it through Teams instead of S4B, like *you yourself* indicated in the question?

Answer (score 3):

APIs to get/set user’s presence status is not available yet. It's on the API roadmap but it's not possible as of today

Comment: Is there another way to detect if user online or not? Like trying to send a message to user and look for response which reactive to user's status?